# OOP concepts in Python

Tags: python, oop

Can any one suggest any links where Python object oriented concepts are clearly explained with example..

```
Data Abstraction 
Encapsulation 
Class 
Object
Datahiding
Inheritance 
Polymorphism
```

Comment: There is no right answer to this question, you're just asking for suggestions / a list-o-links. Please ask specific programming questions that have a "right answer".

Comment: It's not even clear whether you already understand the concepts and want to see how they "work" in Python code; or if you want to learn the concepts by using Python to test them out; or just what exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good starting point: [Introduction to OOP with Python](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/OOP.shtml).